# TinyMCE Spellchecker in Pylons

Tags: python, tinymce, pylons, spell-checking, pyenchant

I've been trying to get the TinyMCE spellchecker working with my Pylons app. My first problem is actually capturing the post data in the first place. Firebug tells me that the following is being sent:

```
{"id":"c0","method":"checkWords","params":["en",["Lorem","ipsum","dolor","sit","amet","consectetur","adipisicing","elit","sed","do","eiusmod","tempor","incididunt","ut","labore","et","dolore","magna","aliqua","Ut","enim","ad","minim","veniam","quis","nostrud","exercitation","ullamco","laboris","nisi","aliquip","ex","ea","commodo","consequat","Duis","aute","irure","in","reprehenderit","voluptate","velit","esse","cillum","eu","fugiat","nulla","pariatur","Excepteur","sint","occaecat","cupidatat","non","proident","sunt","culpa","qui","officia","deserunt","mollit","anim","id","est","laborum"]]}
```

Which looks like a string of JSON. That's fine, I can handle that but it's not coming up in my request.params dict anywhere. Does anyone have any experience in getting this to work with Pylons or some things for me to try? I know spellchecker was intended to work with a PHP backend but that shouldn't throw up any significant barriers, should it?

Furthermore can anyone provide any insight as to what the response is supposed to look like? The documentation for this plugin seems to be woefully incomplete.

Comment: Forget about it :) Turns out it was being sent in the body.

Answer (score 1):

That's not really an answer to your question but I hope it will help:

You maybe interested to look at [django-tinymce](http://code.google.com/p/django-tinymce/) as a source of inspiration. The spellchecker is based on PyEnchant